# Sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats shows high latency for tempdb writes

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, waits

We just got a new SAN and I was looking at sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats to make sure we are seeing an improvement compared to our last SAN. I noticed that all the tempdb files are seeing avg write latencies of about 350ms. This is still an improvement as our last SAN had stats of 1000ms avg write for tempdb in sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats but not as good as I hoped.

Looking at the `win.disk.duration` perfmon counter on our tempdb drive for the past three days (since boot) the avg disk latency is < 1ms. Sometimes there are spikes to 150ms for one interval (30 seconds).

Looking at our SAN's monitoring tools it says the LUN has an avg write latency of 0.5ms.

VMWares stats are pretty much inline with the win.disk.duration perfmon counters.

Any pointers to where I should look at next to work out what is causing the discrepancy between Sql Servers io stats and perfmon/vmware/san monitoring stats?

Comment: What's the connection from the server to the SAN?

Comment: What statement are you issuing to determine the average write latency in ms?

Comment: @sp_BlitzEric we are using 10gb iSCSI. Each esxi host has two dedicated iSCSI nics.

Comment: @hot2use I am using the query on this page. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-to-examine-io-subsystem-latencies-from-within-sql-server/

Comment: Seen the note in the original post? _The best way to use this data for analysis is to periodically capture snapshots of the sys.dm_db_io_virtual_file stats data and then examine the averages over that small time period. That way you’ll be able to see latency spikes. [link to second script](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-io-latencies-period-time/)_

Comment: @MichaelHolzheimer - could this be a case where Instant File Initialization is not enabled and you're encountering frequent file growth events on tempdb data files?  The OS may think the latency is fine, but SQL Server may be waiting for the growth event to complete.

Comment: @hot2use I’ll give that a go in the morning.

Comment: @ScottHodgin it could be, I’ll check it in the morning.

Comment: Normally, SAN software aggregates an average over a period of time. For example, you've stated that there are spikes for 30 seconds and an unknown but smaller amount of IO. Now take into account a 15 minute slice which the SAN software *generally* aggregates to. That 30 second spike of 5000 IOs is not even a *blip* to the 15 million IO it just did in 15 minutes, thus you have a smooth line. The fact you can see the latency in VMWare means that's the truth, the hypervisor is handing it off and seeing the latency so it's either the fabric or the SAN.

Comment: (2/2) The other possibility is that there is a misconfiguration at the VMware level, but since it was a direct port from one device to another and the results are better, I'm going to *assume* this wasn't it. There could still be imposed queueing under high IO workloads, depending on setup of the adaptor, registry, and a few other items in VMware afaik.

Comment: I made a script to log avg latency in 1m intervals based on the link @hot2use gave. At around 1:40 am there were several spikes between 4000ms and 9000ms avg write latency based of the stats from sys.dm_db_io_virtual_file. The stats from win.disk.duration during this time where usually .5ms to 2ms with a single spike to 112ms. Instant file initialisation was already turned on, and I verified that there was no file growth in temp db at this time.